# Had to reinstall Ubuntu, now it won't connect to my WiFi at home

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I had to reinstall Ubuntu due to it failing to boot (stuck on /dev/sda1 clean ...).

Now for some strange reason it won't connect to my WiFi at home (same router as before), although the connection worked during the reinstallation. I tried with another WiFi from a phone hotspot and it worked with no problems...

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: a0:88:b4:d9:a7:04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:28 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
```

It seems like the problem lies with DHCP, if I manually assign a static IP it works...strange. And I can connect to any other WiFi except this one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
gksu nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Restart nework manager :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You find a reference of some fixes here :

[Fix: Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 WiFi and Ethernet Problem](https://appuals.com/ubuntu-16-04-to-17-10-wifi-and-ethernet-problem/)

Comment: That only applied for Ubuntu 17.04 which is unsupported now, it was fixed in 17.10

Comment: The only correct statement in the link you posted is "The result is that those USB WiFi adapters cannot connect anymore to the WiFi network" and that only applied to 17.04.  I have no idea who wrote that but it could have been a lot better.  I don't understand why they wouldn't have used a dkms install for the rtl8188eu at the bottom as my github was mentioned and it does have dkms support.  Oh, the writer is  a certified MCTS (Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist) with over 10 years of experience, that explains everything

Comment: " Oh, the writer is a certified MCTS (Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist) with over 10 years of experience, " LOL :D:D

Comment: These lines are already in the config file...